# android:onProgressChanged doesn't exists in seekbar

Tags: android, kotlin, seekbar, android-seekbar

I am trying to listen to `seekbar`'s `progress` change from a `viewmodel` using `dataBinding` and `LiveData` but the `android:onProgressChanged` doesn't exists in the `xml` `view` of the `seekbar`.
Previously i was listening to it's progress programmatically from an activity but i can't do that now.

Can anyone tell me what to do?
The main thing i want is to listen to `seekbar`'s `progressChange` in the `viewmodel` using `LiveData`.

Here's my `SeekBar`:

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onProgressChanged=""         // doesn't exists
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:max="200"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seekbar"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_bg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11" />
```

Comment: can you post the complete XML of the layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not expose a binding against 'progress' like this

```
<SeekBar
  android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
  android:progress="@={viewModel.value}"
  ...
```

That way you can observe changes of `viewModel.value`

Comment: Ahh.. I was trying to avoid two way data binding because the official documentation doesn't completely explain how to use that and all the resources they have provided are basically outdated. But this the only way i could achieve the feature i want. So i am going to implement this with the half knowledge i have on two way databinding.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best way to update and read data for progress bar is **AsyncTask**

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using AsyncTask, its been deprecated since Android API 30